# How to do date and time comparision with a calculated date time value

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

Can I check if a date and time field less 15 minutes is smaller or equal the current date and time in a workflow condition?

For example, if my value is 5:40 pm, I will have to check if the current date and time is smaller than 5:25 pm to get into a condition. How can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Sharepoint Designer:

Create a local variable. Its type must be Date/Time.

Set it's value to the relevant date.

Now, the next thing you do is use the **Add Time to Date** function (type "time" and choose the first option (at least that's the position in Sharepoint Designer 2010, which I'm using). Add 15 minutes to your variable.

Now just create another local Date/Time variable, set it to the current date and compare both.